# New CentOS 7 user - have I installed an application

Tags: installation, centos, gedit

I have installed CentOS 7 linux system and tried to install anaconda python 3.6.0. I am totally new to GNOME and fairly new to Linux.

I try to install python 3.6. I have downloaded a bash script, that is `Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`. I tried to open the file to see the script and I think I have made something wrong. I have seen **gedit** is a default application. I opened **gedit**, dragged and dropped the file into its window and **gedit** froze for a few minutes. Then it closed itself.

I don't know what happened. I went to Anaconda website and the instructions are completely different. Can I revert what **gedit** did?

So the main question is: if you open a bash script in **gedit**, does it run the script?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your question ? you don't remember where you downloaded the script ?

Comment: No, I know where the script is! I opened this bash script (*.sh) using __gedit__. I was wondering if __gedit__ executes script if it's bash! If so, it means it would run and install Anaconda. I was wondering, where the package can be found in the system.

Comment: No opening with gedit doesn't execute the script.

Comment: Thanks for help. I thought __gedit__ did something as it froze for a minute or two after opening the file. it seemed to process the file.